# When to use BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3), BIOMETRIC_WEAK (Class 2) and DEVICE_CREDENTIAL?

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am working on the biometrics authentication, but I have no idea about which biometric level to use. Can Someone help me understand when should I use BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3), BIOMETRIC_WEAK (Class 2) and DEVICE_CREDENTIAL? Thank you:)